# "constexpr if" not support alias using?

Tags: c++, c++17

I compile the code using gcc7.1, but got some compile error:

error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’

error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’

```
class Test
{
    int a{1};
    string b{"test"};
    public:
          template <int N> auto & get()
          {
             if constexpr (N==0)
                 return a;
             else
                 return b;
          }
};

namespace std {
    template<> struct tuple_size<Test> { static const int value = 2; };
    template<size_t N> struct tuple_element<N, Test>
    {
        if constexpr (N==0)  //error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’
            using type = int;
        else                 //error: expected unqualified-id before ‘else’
          using type = string;
        //using type = conditional_t<N==0, int, string>; //this works
    };
}
```

Comment: There were two `static if` proposals around 2013 that would have enabled this, but which were rejected by the Committee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A constexpr `if` statement is still an `if` statement and can only appear in contexts where an `if` statement can be used.

That doesn't include class (template) definitions.

Comment: @tc  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would suggest using `std::enable_if` or `std::conditional` for this purpose